# How do I sync shared folders to my WordPress directory?

Tags: vagrant, shared-folders, wordpress

How can I get my scripts in data folder synced to the wordpress themes folder?

Currently I've got it set from this:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/vagrant_data"
```

to this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/var/www/public_html/wpthemes/wp-content/themes/UberBasic/"
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have VirtualBox guest additions installed in the box your are using to get this working.

If you are using default boxes like debian/stretch64, it does not include VirtualBox guest additions, so you need to install it manually.

To do so you need :
* to add guest addition iso cdrom in VirtualBox GUI and mount it

[image: VirtualBoxGUI]

In your console/terminal :

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
mkdir /opt/tempdir
mount /dev/sr0 /opt/tempdir
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-amd64 build-essentials
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
rm -fr /opt/tempdir
```

You need to shutdown the vm, modify the Vagrantfile to allow synced folder :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/var/www/public_html/wpthemes/wp-content/themes/UberBasic/"
```

You can start your vm with vagrant up.
After that you will have a full synced folder between vagrant host and guest.

Be aware that if you use vagrant destroy, you will have to repeat all from the beginning.

Or you can also use a Vagrant box with VB guest additions embedded which is more simpler.